# Trying to select forum threads with new posts

Tags: java, selenium

Hello everyone I'm learning Selenium with Java. How can I select forum threads with new posts (posts the user has not already posted in).

Example of my assignment:

> Given the list of threads at: http://siteownersforums.com/forumdisplay.php?s=ea4353212d6e4bcb50abb3f5790fa97a&f=3
>
> Open each new thread that you haven't posted in. Hint: You'll want to
>   select the elements first, and then use the .click() method.

and this is what I have so far:

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Set the Driver and the Webpage. 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver");
    WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    chromeDriver.get("http://siteownersforums.com/forumdisplay.php?s=ea4353212d6e4bcb50abb3f5790fa97a&f=3");
    //Confirmation
    System.out.println("Successfully Opened up: "+ chromeDriver.getTitle());

    //Select each of the threads and click it. 
    for (int i =0; i< 27; i++){
        WebElement tempThread = chromeDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));
        tempThread.click();
    }

    }//Closes method test
}//Closes class
```

Comment: Have you written any code at all to try to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide your code because if not, what are you doing but asking us to do your homework for free? :)

Comment: @DavidConrad yes I just posted it :)